Why does Crystal Field Splitting Energy increase significantly down a group?
"Crystal Field Splitting Energy increases significantly down a group because of size of metal d-orbitals which increases the repulsion to Ligand-electrons" - ppt for topic on d-orbitals at uni.
Referring specifically to these effects:

(crystal field splitting energy on the right given in units of cm-1).
Yes I can see that is the case, but why? If anything, having larger electron orbitals should lead to less repulsion (and stabilisation in the case of CFSE) from L-electrons, since they are less electron dense; bigger orbital doesnt mean more electrons. Additionally, larger metal ions would attract Ligands less closely since they are less electropositive (charge/size), this would mean that ligands are further away and less repulsive. This previous statement I think is the part that I could be getting wrong because, to explain why larger metal d-orbitals cause more L-electron repulsion, the ppt has an attached image:
I feel that this diagram only shows that the ligands in metal complexes are closer to surrounding ligands because they're bigger and therefore closer because theyre bigger than the smaller ones (duh!). Besides being an annoying 'isn't it obvious already?' way of explaining this phenomenon, surely it is not very accurate and not always true; whilst larger metal ions cover a greater distance to the ligands they are attracting, this also has to be matched to the fact that simultaneously they are further away from the ligands they are attracting since larger ion, less effective nuclear attraction, more effective electron repulsion.
This metal ion size and repulsion effect has been explained using the Crystal Field Theory electrostatic repulsion/attraction model of bonding within a complex, which might be why it doesn't really make sense, since it is based off a reductionist model. I think using Ligand Field Theory (the Molecular Orbitals one), the description of metal ion size causing increased repulsion relative to the amount that it also distances itself from its respective ligand would be much more apt, since bonding forces in LFT are much more well-defined and restrictive than a purely electrostatic forces approach.
Anyway, I'm sure I've got a lot of this wrong so please let me know where and what I'm misunderstanding. Might just be that they forgot to scale the second image or that whilst larger ions are further away from the ligands they attract, this effect is negligible, or something like that.

The Fe-O and the Ru-O bond lengths seem to be rather similar and so as the 4d orbitals are bigger one would expect, just on a Coulomb interaction argument, more interaction and so bigger splitting in the Ru. In Co and Rh the Rh-O bond is shorter than the Co-O bond and so the Rh-O interaction should be bigger anyway. However, this is a very simple explanation, and the full one is undoubtably more involved.
